# How to config Web References in Visual Studio for production environment

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing an application which will upload documents to a sharepoint folder. Because my application will not run on a server environment, but in client machines, I decided to user the Web Services provided by Sharepoint to upload the documents (`my sharepoint address` + **_vti_bin/copy.asmx**) and check in the uploaded files (`my sharepoint address` + **/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx**).

My problem is with the `my sharepoint address` part. The Sharepoint I am using for development is of course different from the that the clients use. Since I have to add the Web References for the service at developing time in order to use it in the C# code, how should I approach?

I will have to obtain at least obtain the main parte of the sharepoint address - say `https://sharepoint/projects/ProjectX/`and declare my WS with it?

If it makes different, I am using WiX to deploy my application in the end, generating a .msi executable. My sharepoint is 2010 and I'm writing my application in VS2010 using .NET 4.0.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats Correct Pedro.

You should point `my sharepoint address` to the url of the website, not root site collection, but website you want to access the services.

You have then 2 options, you can change the address on the configuration file that the visual studio proxy generates as part of the build scripts (sorry dont know Wix, but I bet it can be done)

Or you can then set the url at runtime, it will ignore the one in the config file generated by Visual Studio:

```
WSS.Lists svc = new WSS.Lists();
svc.Url = my sharepoint address + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
```

Comment: Good! That second option looks really promising. I will try it out and return with results.

Answer (score 1):

Luis's answer is pretty much correct. Another approach you can do is create proxy classes using wsdl.exe. This creates a class instance which you can use in your project. Once you have the file you can just update the value of the variable **URL** so that it matches your sharepoint URL.

You can also update the constructor like below:

```
public Lists(string SERVER)
{
    this.Url = "http://" + SERVER + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
}
```

This makes sure that you can use whatever SharePoint site you want or place it in configuration files too.

Comment: In both cases, do I have to set the Web Service references in the solution or handling the server like you are describing is enough?

Comment: Humm, *it will ignore the one in the config file generated by Visual Studio* I guess answers my question!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)